# Central limit type theorems for compact Hausdorff topological groups?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, harmonic-analysis

Given a compact Hausdorff topological group $G$ and probability measures $\mu$ and $\tau$ on the Borel sets of $G$, their convolution is the probability measure

$(\tau*\mu)(A)=\int\int1_A(xy)d\tau(x)d\mu(y)$.

A useful interpretation of this is that $G$ is a permutation group of some deck of cards, $\mu$ describes the distribution of arrangements the deck could currently be in, $\tau$ describes a shuffling scheme i.e. the distribution of possible shuffles a dealer may apply to randomize the deck. The convolution $\tau*\mu$ is then the distribution of the arrangements of the deck after the dealer has shuffled it. For example if $\tau$ and $\mu$ are Dirac measures supported at $g_1$ and $g_2$ respectively then $\tau*\mu$ is the Dirac measure supported at $g_1g_2$.

It is helpful to note that if $\tau_0$ is the unique Haar probability measure on $G$ and $\mu$ is another probability measure, then $\tau_0*\mu=\tau_0$. The interpretation here is that $\tau_0$ is the best shuffling scheme: every arrangement of the deck is equally likely after applying it, independent of how the deck is initially arranged. Obviously it's desirable for a shuffler to use such a scheme, or at least a scheme which converges to $\tau_0$. This is my motivation.

I am interested in the following questions:

1. For which distributions $\tau$ does the sequence of convolutions $\tau^{*n}=\tau*\tau*\ldots*\tau$ converge, let's say weakly, to the Haar distribution $\tau_0$? My first guess is these are at least the distributions whose support generates $G$. Related to this, can the speed of convergence be measured? I know of such a result for the usual central limit theorem due to Berry and Esseen.
2. Which distributions $\mu$ on $G$ are infinitely divisible in the sense that for any $n\geq 1$ there is a distribution $\tau_n$ such that $\mu=\tau_n^{*n}$? For example, the Haar distribution is infinitely divisible, but there are more: if $g\in G$ always has an $n$-th root $g_n$, then the Dirac measure supported at $g$ is infinitely divisible: $\delta_g = \delta_{g_n}^{*n}$. What are all the infinitely divisible distributions for $G=S^1$?

If someone can point me toward a reference for any of this I would much appreciate it, I don't know much harmonic analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For instance, in the recent [paper by Harremoes, page 12](https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.0015) one finds this:

> **Corollary 20.** Let $P$ be a probability measure on the compact group $G$ with Haar probability measure
>   $U$.  Assume that the support of $P$ is not contained in any coset of a proper subgroup of $G$. Then $P^{*n}$ 
>   converges to $U$ in the weak topology.

(See also the note in first paragraph on page 5 of that paper.)

Some results on a geometric rate of the convergence are given in Section 6 of the same paper.

It also contains a number of useful references.

Comment: Excellent, I believe this sufficiently answers my first question.

Comment: It is competely misleading to attribute this result to Harremoes as it was explicitly formulated and proved by Stromberg in 1960. It is amazing that Harremoes actually quotes Stromberg's paper (in a somewhat vague form), but fails to mention that his Corollary 20 is due to Stromberg.

Comment: Thank you for that comment, I was able to find the paper: [Stromberg](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1960-094-02/S0002-9947-1960-0114874-4/S0002-9947-1960-0114874-4.pdf). I agree it looks like all credit belongs to Stromberg, but I wasn't able to find a comment on the speed of convergence in this paper.

Comment: As for the exponential speed of convergence in the total variation metric - it has also been known for ages and goes essentially back to Doeblin. Harremoes actually quotes (in Corollary 25) a paper of Kloss from 1959 where this was explicitly done for compact groups. In what concerns the speed of convergence in the weak topology, it can be measured by using the transportation metric, and it is known that the convergence can be arbitrarily slow, see https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=816292

Comment: Thank you these have been very helpful.

Comment: By the way, for the general background you may look at Heyer's book "Probability Measures on Locally Compact Groups" - it's a bit dated and in places boring, but still provides a good introduction.

Comment: @RW : I certainly did not "attribute this result to Harremoes". Instead, I said "one finds this" result in his paper and "It also contains a number of useful references." In particular, Harremoes does refer to Stromberg 1960: "Convergence of convolutions of probability measures were [sic] studied by Stromberg [10] who proved weak convergence of convolutions of probability measures." I think an advantage of Harremoes' paper is that it is comparatively recent and presents more of the more recent history.

Comment: Dear Iosif - if one says that a result A is found in Statement B of paper C by author D, this Statement B is quoted in full and contains no reference whatsoever to any earlier work, then it means precisely that result A is attributed to D. As for the advantages of Harremoes' paper - I am not sure he fully understands what he is writing about, as, for instance, in Section 2 he reinvents the transportation metric (which metrizes the weak topology) without ever mentioning its long and glorious history.

Comment: @RW : I am sorry if you understood "one finds this" result in a paper by author A as an attribution of the result to author A. I knew that this result was proved long before Harremoes' paper. I did think about inserting a sentence about Stromberg's paper into my answer, but then decided that to say "It [the paper] also contains a number of useful references" would be enough. If I only had known the dire consequences of that fateful decision ... :-)